# What is glassfish-jvm-option "http.proxyHost" for / when to use it?

Tags: proxy, glassfish, jvm-arguments

I have just setup my glassfish-as behind a HAProxy.

I found the glassfish-jvm-option "java.http.proxyHost"¹ and "java.http.proxyPort"¹. I have not set this value in my glassfish, so I am asking myself: What do I need this value(s) for, when should I set them?

¹ http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/820-7203/gigbs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need these options if you have a normal proxy server in front of your glassfish and want the glassfish server to connect through the proxy. Just the standard proxy stuff.

In your case these settings are not required because you only "proxy" the requests from the net to your glassfish server and the response is sent directly from the glassfish server to the client.

More detailed information can be found in ["Java Networking and Proxies"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).